# How to typeset a curly braced column vector

Tags: braces, vector

How to write this

[image]

Ignore underbrace and the vector's content. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular `array` with `\left\{` and `\right\}` fences would accommodate for any number of internal elements to your vector.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
    \alpha_1^{(e)} \\
    \alpha_2^{(e)} \\
    \alpha_3^{(e)}
  \end{array}\right\}
  \qquad
  \underbrace{
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \alpha_1^{(e)} \\
      \alpha_2^{(e)} \\
      \alpha_3^{(e)}
    \end{array}\right\}
  }_{\alpha^{(e)}}
  \qquad
  \underbrace{
    \hspace*{-20pt}
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \alpha_1^{(e)} \\
      \alpha_2^{(e)} \\
      \alpha_3^{(e)}
    \end{array}\right\}
    \hspace*{-20pt}
  }_{\alpha^{(e)}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `amsmath` package provides `Bmatrix` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{Bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `amsmath` package provides an environment called `Bmatrix` to encase matrices (including, naturally, column and row vectors) in curly braces. However, the `Bmatrix` braces aren't actually all that curly. For *really curly* braces, I suggest you download the [mtpro2 font package](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) -- it's a commercial package, but its "lite" subset is free of charge -- and use its `\lcbrace` and `\rcbrace` macros to encase the matrix/row vector/column vector of interest.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}       % for 'Bmatrix' environment
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}  % cf. https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html

\begin{document}
$\begin{Bmatrix} 1\\2\\3\\4\\5 \end{Bmatrix}$ \quad
$\LEFTRIGHT\lcbrace\rcbrace{\begin{array}{c} 1\\2\\3\\4\\5 \end{array}}$ 
\end{document}
```